# Extract values from text strings using Matlab's sscanf

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, text

I have the following string:

```
str={"USD":{"last":352.49,"bid":352.49,"ask":353.6,
            "high":358.75,"low":349.34,"volume":6678.7783}.....
```

and I would like to extract the values in a column vector like this

```
colvector=[352.49,352.49,353.6,358.75,349.34,6678.7783]
```

I believe the `sscanf` function can be useful to extract the desirable format. I tried different variations of using `sscanf`, but I haven't managed to extract the values from the string.

```
fmt=['{"USD":{"last": "%f", "bid": "%f", "ask": "%f",
              "high": "%f", "low": "%f", "volume": "%f"}...
```

For example `colvector=sscanf(str,fmt)` was not working successfully.

Comment: Is it a string variable (wrong syntax then) or a _file_'s contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a string variable containing that text,

```
s = 'str={"USD":{"last":352.49,"bid":352.49,"ask":353.6,"high":358.75,"low":349.34,"volume":6678.7783}.';
```

you can apply a regular expression to isolate the desired strings (consisting of digits followed optionally by a decimal point and digits). For that you use the [`regexp`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) function with the `'match'` option. This produces a cell array of strings. You then convert each string into a number using [`cellfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) with [`str2num`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html). Combining everything into a single line,

```
result = cellfun(@str2num, regexp(s, '\d+(\.\d+)?', 'match'));
```

For the example string, this produces:

```
result =

  1.0e+003 *

    0.3525    0.3525    0.3536    0.3588    0.3493    6.6788
```